# Not able to see FailureText on failed login

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to this so bear with me. I'm trying to get the FailureText to display once the login has failed. This is from my Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(1) from UserInfo WHERE EmailAddress = '" + Login1.UserName + "' AND Password = '" + Login1.Password + "'", con);
    int reader = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    if (reader == 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("FormsTest.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Literal lit1 = (Literal)Login1.FindControl("FailureText");
        lit1.Visible = true;       

        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");

    }
}
```

I set the Visible property inside the Literal to true, and that does display my text. I'm kind of just lost as to why my text won't show when I use FindControl to find ID:FailureText, and attempting to set lit1.Visible to true. Here's my login.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="LoginSample2._0.Login" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <!-- adding css to the login page only -->

    <style>
    .Login{
        background-image: url('Images/newHOA50.png');
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin:auto;
    }
    
    
    .newStyle1 {
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
    
    
    .auto-style1 {
        text-decoration: underline;
        font-size: x-large;
    }
    .newStyle2 {
        font-family: "Javanese Text";
    }
    .newStyle3 {
        font-family: "freestyle Script";
    }
    .newStyle4 {
        font-family: "Edwardian Script ITC";
    }
    .newStyle5 {
        font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    .newStyle6 {
        font-family: "segoe script";
    }
    .auto-style2 {
        height: 5px;
    }
    .newStyle7 {
        font-family: "lucida handwriting";
    }
    
    
    .auto-style4 {
        height: 112px;
    }
    
    
    .auto-style5 {
        width: 380px;
    }
    .remember{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .auto-style5{
        text-align:left;
        padding-left: 10%;
    }

    
    
    .auto-style7 {
        width: 175px;
    }

    
    
    </style>
    <!--login version 1 -->

    <asp:Login Class="Login" ID="Login1" runat="server" Height="400px" Width="500px">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table cellpadding="0" style="height:400px;width:500px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" class="auto-style1" colspan="2"><span class="newStyle7">HOA Login</span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" class="auto-style7">Email:</td>
                                <td class="auto-style5">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="UserName_TextChanged" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" class="auto-style7">
                                    <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td class="auto-style5">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Width="180px"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class ="remember" colspan="2">
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me?" OnCheckedChanged="RememberMe_CheckedChanged"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;" class="auto-style2">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" Visible="False" ></asp:Literal>
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" colspan="2" class="auto-style4">
                                    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" CssClass="newStyle1" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Login1" OnClick="LoginButton_Click" />
                                    <a runat="server" class="nav-link" href="~/ForgotPassword">
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GVTDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [UserInfo]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    </a>
                                    <br />
                                    <a  class="nav-link" runat="server" href="~/ForgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:Login>    
</asp:Content>
```